# How to turn off php-indent warning in Emacs

Tags: php, html, emacs, elisp, emacs23

When editing a PHP file with PHP code and HTML markup in Emacs, I continue to get the warning:

```
Warning (php-indent):
        Indentation fails badly with mixed HTML and PHP.
        Look for an Emacs Lisp library that supports "multiple
        major modes" like mumamo, mmm-mode or multi-mode.
```

which pops up at the bottom of my wiindow and takes up half of my editing screen.  How do I turn this off?

I know there are various "add-ons" and modes that you can add to make Emacs format PHP + HTML nicely but **I just want to turn the warning off**.  How can I do so?

EDIT:

Here is a portion of the `php-mode.el` file where the above error seems to be coming from:

```el
(defvar php-completion-table nil
  "Obarray of tag names defined in current tags table and functions know to PHP.")

(defvar php-warned-bad-indent nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'php-warned-bad-indent)

;; Do it but tell it is not good if html tags in buffer.
(defun php-check-html-for-indentation ()
  (let ((html-tag-re "</?\\sw+.*?>")
        (here (point)))
    (if (not (or (re-search-forward html-tag-re (line-end-position) t)
                 (re-search-backward html-tag-re (line-beginning-position) t)))
        t
      (goto-char here)
      (setq php-warned-bad-indent t)
      (lwarn 'php-indent :warning
             "\n\t%s\n\t%s\n\t%s\n"
             "Indentation fails badly with mixed HTML and PHP."
             "Look for an Emacs Lisp library that supports \"multiple"
             "major modes\" like mumamo, mmm-mode or multi-mode.")
      nil)))

(defun php-cautious-indent-region (start end &optional quiet)
  (if (or php-warned-bad-indent
          (php-check-html-for-indentation))
      (funcall 'c-indent-region start end quiet)))

(defun php-cautious-indent-line ()
  (if (or php-warned-bad-indent
          (php-check-html-for-indentation))
      (funcall 'c-indent-line)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grepping the Emacs source code, I do not find that message anywhere. It is probably coming from some other code that you load from your init file.

Check the libraries that you load -- `grep` them for the message. That will give you an idea how to inhibit the message.  It depends how it is created etc.

You can probably advise (`defadvice`) the function that issues the message, for instance, but you might have to use the advice to replace the function's code by similar code that does not issue the message.

But find the culprit code first.  There might be an easy way to inhibit the message, such as a user option.

UPDATE ---

OK, so the function issuing the warning is `lwarn`. Right away, you can, at least as a workaround, customize option `warning-minimum-level` and possibly `warning-minimum-log-level`, to inhibit the warning.  But that will also inhibit other warnings of the same level.

The function that calls `lwarn` is `php-check-html-for-indentation`, and it calls it unconditionally. 
Search the code for calls to `php-check-html-for-indentation`, to see if perhaps that function is called conditionally. With luck there is a condition (perhaps even a user option) you can set or change that will inhibit `php-check-html-for-indentation` from being called.

If inhibiting `php-check-html-for-indentation` would not be the right thing, because of other stuff it does besides warn, then your best approach is to advise  `php-check-html-for-indentation`, essentially redefining it as is, but without the call to `lwarn`. To do that, your `defadvice` for `php-check-html-for-indentation` would reuse the original definition, but without the call to `lwarn` and without any `ad-do-it`.  See the Elisp manual, nodes `Advising Functions` and `Around Advice`.

Comment: The warning is in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/php-mode.el`.  How do i check the libraries that I load?  I see only the following set in my `.emacs` file: `(setq diff-switches "-u")` AND `(setq frame-title-format (concat  "%b - emacs@" (system-name)))`

Comment: `php-mode.el` is not part of Emacs (i.e., `emacs -Q`), as far as I can see.  You must have gotten it somewhere else. Try `M-x find-library php-mode`.  That should take you to file `php-mode.el`, which you can search for the message.

Comment: I have found the file and the message is there.  I just don't know how to turn the "feature" off.  I can post the contents of the `php-mode.el` file if that would help.

Comment: Yes, please do. Not the whole file, just the function that issues the message. Dunno whether we can help, but without seeing the code it is impossible to make a suggestion.

Comment: Updated my question with more details. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I eventually found that the changes I was making wasn't taking effect and found a solution [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.os.linux.misc/cUPDbZmJHaQ/Do7yU8EdGq8J)

Answer (score 1):

There is a conditional in the two functions that call it. Go to your `.emacs` file and add the following line:

`(setq php-mode-warn-if-mumamo-off nil)`

And that should take care of your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a line from that code snippet you so helpfully found, I put

```
(setq php-warned-bad-indent t)
```

in my .emacs file. Tested and worked for me.

(I can't believe I just posted an answer that involves Lisp.)